# Which type(s) of circumcision is/are valid by the Islamic rules?

Tags: sharia, circumcision

There are four main categories of male circumcision. i.e.:

1. Low and Loose
2. Low and Tight
3. High and Loose
4. High and Tight

- Which one(s) of these are valid as-per the Islamic rules? Meaning which one of these fulfill the requirement(s) that Islam mandates in order for the circumcision to be considered valid? Or else it's not.
- Are there any mandatory requirement(s) for a Islamic circumcision? If so what are they?
- What's ruling on the removal of the frenulum?

Answer (score 2):

"Khitaan" in Arabic means the act of circumcising or being circumcised.

It's true that circumcision is not mentioned in the Quran.

But it's not true that it's an old Arabic custom, because there are hieroglyphics in Egypt showing that ancient Egyptians use to practice circumcision.

In Islam, circumcision is not obligatory.  It's something permissible for both male and female.  There's no ayah or Sahih hadith obligating us to do circumcision.

There's no authentic evidence telling us that Prophet Mohammed himself was circumcised.  We don't know if he was or if he wasn't.

There's no particular method of circumcision mentioned in the Quran or sahih hadiths.  Therefore, it's whatever is best and medically proven.

Comment: "But it's not true that it's an old Arabic custom, because there are hieroglyphics in Egypt showing that ancient Egyptians use to practice circumcision." Huh? Are you saying that because it was Egyptian, it could not also be Arabic?

Answer (score 1):

The Qu'ran never mentions circumcision. It is mentioned in only one hadith. Several that would be expected to mention it do not. It seems to be an old Arabic custom that crept into Islam by mistake. http://www.circumstitions.com/Islam.html

The four categories you mention are only of interest to circumcision fetishists. Since circumcision in Islam is done in the name of ritual cleanliness, the frenulum is of no concern, but since (like the foreskin) it is important for sexual functioning, it should certainly be left.

Comment: " It seems to be an old Arabic custom that crept into Islam by mistake" ??? are the jews following an _old arabic custom_?

Comment: so even jews follow this ryt? @MAKZ

Comment: @servantofWiser Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_male_circumcision#In_Judaism

Comment: so with this I guess, these rules are automatically applied to Muslims also unless until any corrections or abrogations are made by prophet Muhammad (pbuh). @MAKZ